# Cheap way to reset all margin and padding

Tags: css

I am building a site where performance is critical and the by far heaviest css-selector is

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Is there a cheaper way to remove all margin and padding without loosing the convenience this selector offers?

**Update:** Yes, using a tested library is a good idea, but I would appreciate if anyone could prove "cheaper" with data

Comment: Only certain elements have margin and padding by default. You should be overriding them with your own, not nuking them all.

Answer (score 2):

Try to list all elements this way (more infos http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ ):

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, choose what elements really need to be changed. This is cheaper and I use it in all my projects:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: In what way is this actually "cheaper", though?  It is larger, so will take (infinitessimally) longer to download, and is a more complex selector so the browser will take longer when searching for rules to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some frameworks like Boilerplatte or Bootstrap. They all have reset entries in their CSS, and are known to be optimized for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes use css reset , i this is what i use, you can make your own depending upon which elements you are going to use

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
  v2.0 | 20110126
  License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}

table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

No.  There is nothing you can do to this selector that will result in any noticeable performance improvement.

Comment: Could people downvoting please explain why they think this is wrong?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but could you provide a source for the claim that the OP's CSS can't be optimized? I thought it was common knowledge that the usage of `*` should be avoided because of performance issues.

Comment: My claim is not that it can't be optimized, but that any issues produced by it are trivial.

Comment: See a relatively complex example page here: http://jsfiddle.net/wpuFk/ - benchmarking using Chrome Speed Test and then adding the CSS from the question and benchmarking again shows no obvious difference - in each case page rendering takes about 10ms.

Comment: A further reference: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/03/10/performance-impact-of-css-selectors/

Comment: And: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/#comment-656